# Excel 2010 VSE 2012 C# dll and tlb - Can't create reference to specified file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, typelib

I'm interested in finding how to call C# code from Excel, and have been following the method here https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/.

The C# code is a "Hello World" example, called DotNetClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DotNetLibrary
{
    public class DotNetClass
    {
        public string DotNetMethod(string input)
        {
            return "Hello " + input;
        }
    }
}
```

The build configuration has "Register for COM interop" and "Make assembly COM-visible" checked. I also have the options ".NET Framework 4.5" and "Any CPU" (I'm working on a 64bit machine). I have tried a few NET versions and CPU options without success. I have cleaned and rebuilt it several times.

In Excel 2010 I cannot create a reference to DotNetLibrary.dll. I can browse to it, and I can even create a reference to a file in the same place - DotNetLibrary.tlb.

The call from Excel is

```
Private Sub TestDotNetCall()
Dim testClass As New DotNetClass
MsgBox testClass.DotNetMethod(“World”)
End Sub
```

... and this works - almost. If I run the VBA code (F5), I get a MsgBox (woot!) with the message "Hello " (no "World" - unwoot!). So, it seems to be ignoring the argument ("World"), which appears to defeat the purpose of doing this.

I'd appreciate any explanations. Is it a good thing to reference the tlb file? Why can't I seem to pass the argument to, or get the result from the dll/tlb? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The .dll is your managed assembly, the CLR runs it; the .tlb is the type library you've registered for COM interop - you're doing the right thing. It seems. To me.

Comment: Could you explain a little why are you trying to do this?  I'm asking simply because there are C# libraries to manipulate Excel files.

Comment: @aspiring.algorist Learning how to expose managed code through COM never killed anyone, I mean it's clearly "hello world" experimentation code... *Why* he's doing it is of no relevance to the issue here :)

Comment: @retailcoder: I never said that learning such a thing could have such dastardly consequences :) As I said in my comment, if the goal is to use C# to parse an Excel file, there are other ways to accomplish this.  Besides providing more context to a question has not been known to be harmful either.

Comment: The reason I am doing this is to find out how to do it, and how difficult it might be. What I have in mind is to develop C# code for various bespoke technical/mathematical problems, and then to access them from Excel as a kind of UI. (Of course, I could access them in other ways, but for various reasons, I'm currently looking at Excel.)

Comment: Refer [this link](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/)

Comment: As an alternative you might want to look at Excel DNA which provides an easy and fast-executing way of creating .NET functions that can be called from worksheet formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. The problem arises because C# is strongly typed, and VBA is loosely typed.

In the VBA line

```
MsgBox testClass.DotNetMethod(“World”)
```

A "thing" (technically a `var`, I believe) with the value "World" is passed to DotNetMethod. The problem is that DotNetMethod doesn't know what type of "thing" "World" is, so it ignores it.

The solution is to explictly define the type of "World" in VBA, as follows

```
Private Sub TestDotNetCall()
Dim testClass As New DotNetClass
Dim s As String
s = "World"
MsgBox (testClass.DotNetMethod(s))
End Sub
```

...and, so, "Hello World"